# Azure DevOps Server Copy-Files task 0 matches

Tags: azure-devops

I need help with simple Azure DevOps step - copy-files.
As source used build artifact, and as can see in debug it cntains files.
Files founded in source folder (##[debug]81 results), using default pattern '**' 0 matches found. Why? What i do wrong?

Here below listed step logs with debug parameter enabled

```
2021-10-04T22:58:51.1196062Z ##[debug]Evaluating: succeeded()
2021-10-04T22:58:51.1196219Z ##[debug]Evaluating succeeded:
2021-10-04T22:58:51.1196485Z ##[debug]=> True
2021-10-04T22:58:51.1196861Z ##[debug]Result: True
2021-10-04T22:58:51.1197218Z ##[section]Starting: Copy Files to: C:\Temp2
2021-10-04T22:58:51.1217256Z ==============================================================================
2021-10-04T22:58:51.1217345Z Task         : Copy Files
2021-10-04T22:58:51.1217390Z Description  : Copy files from source folder to target folder using match patterns (The match patterns will only match file paths, not folder paths)
2021-10-04T22:58:51.1217447Z Version      : 2.117.2
2021-10-04T22:58:51.1217489Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2021-10-04T22:58:51.1217532Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=708389)
2021-10-04T22:58:51.1217617Z ==============================================================================
2021-10-04T22:58:51.4096264Z ##[debug]agent.workFolder=C:\agent\_work
2021-10-04T22:58:51.4315119Z ##[debug]loading inputs and endpoints
2021-10-04T22:58:51.4326357Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION_ACCESSTOKEN
2021-10-04T22:58:51.4337876Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SCHEME_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
2021-10-04T22:58:51.4342070Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
2021-10-04T22:58:51.4343687Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_CLEANTARGETFOLDER
2021-10-04T22:58:51.4345585Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_CONTENTS
2021-10-04T22:58:51.4347245Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_FLATTENFOLDERS
2021-10-04T22:58:51.4349129Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_OVERWRITE
2021-10-04T22:58:51.4350930Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_SOURCEFOLDER
2021-10-04T22:58:51.4352803Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_TARGETFOLDER
2021-10-04T22:58:51.4375978Z ##[debug]loaded 9
2021-10-04T22:58:51.4388031Z ##[debug]check path : C:\agent\_work\_tasks\CopyFiles_5bfb729a-a7c8-4a78-a7c3-8d717bb7c13c\2.117.2\task.json
2021-10-04T22:58:51.4391393Z ##[debug]set resource file to: C:\agent\_work\_tasks\CopyFiles_5bfb729a-a7c8-4a78-a7c3-8d717bb7c13c\2.117.2\task.json
2021-10-04T22:58:51.4392155Z ##[debug]system.culture=en-US
2021-10-04T22:58:51.4430148Z ##[debug]Contents=**
2021-10-04T22:58:51.4435856Z ##[debug]SourceFolder=C:\agent\_work\r3\a\_[DEV] Build Broker library and service\drop
2021-10-04T22:58:51.4436015Z ##[debug]check path : C:\agent\_work\r3\a\_[DEV] Build Broker library and service\drop
2021-10-04T22:58:51.4436146Z ##[debug]TargetFolder=C:\Temp2
2021-10-04T22:58:51.4438609Z ##[debug]CleanTargetFolder=false
2021-10-04T22:58:51.4440284Z ##[debug]OverWrite=false
2021-10-04T22:58:51.4441775Z ##[debug]flattenFolders=false
2021-10-04T22:58:51.4444564Z ##[debug]findPath: 'C:\agent\_work\r3\a\_[DEV] Build Broker library and service\drop'
2021-10-04T22:58:51.4451342Z ##[debug]findOptions.followSpecifiedSymbolicLink: 'true'
2021-10-04T22:58:51.4451720Z ##[debug]findOptions.followSymbolicLinks: 'true'2021-10-04T22:58:51.4530296Z ##[debug]  C:\agent\_work\r3\a\_[DEV] Build Broker library and service\drop\Newtonsoft.Json.dll (file)
2021-10-04T22:58:51.4531629Z ##[debug]  C:\agent\_work\r3\a\_[DEV] Build Broker library and service\drop\Newtonsoft.Json.xml (file)
2021-10-04T22:58:51.4533189Z ##[debug]  C:\agent\_work\r3\a\_[DEV] Build Broker library and service\drop\NLog.config (file)
2021-10-04T22:58:51.4534399Z ##[debug]  C:\agent\_work\r3\a\_[DEV] Build Broker library and service\drop\NLog.dll (file)
2021-10-04T22:58:51.4535620Z ##[debug]  C:\agent\_work\r3\a\_[DEV] Build Broker library and service\drop\NLog.xml (file)
...
2021-10-04T22:58:51.4580535Z ##[debug]  C:\agent\_work\r3\a\_[DEV] Build Broker library and service\drop\System.ValueTuple.dll (file)
2021-10-04T22:58:51.4581919Z ##[debug]  C:\agent\_work\r3\a\_[DEV] Build Broker library and service\drop\System.ValueTuple.xml (file)
**2021-10-04T22:58:51.4582548Z ##[debug]81 results**
2021-10-04T22:58:51.4588838Z ##[debug]patternRoot: 'C:\agent\_work\r3\a\_[DEV] Build Broker library and service\drop'
2021-10-04T22:58:51.4591271Z ##[debug]matchOptions.debug: 'false'
2021-10-04T22:58:51.4592008Z ##[debug]matchOptions.nobrace: 'true'
2021-10-04T22:58:51.4592460Z ##[debug]matchOptions.noglobstar: 'false'
2021-10-04T22:58:51.4593053Z ##[debug]matchOptions.dot: 'true'
2021-10-04T22:58:51.4593577Z ##[debug]matchOptions.noext: 'false'
2021-10-04T22:58:51.4594118Z ##[debug]matchOptions.nocase: 'true'
2021-10-04T22:58:51.4594740Z ##[debug]matchOptions.nonull: 'false'
2021-10-04T22:58:51.4595242Z ##[debug]matchOptions.matchBase: 'false'
2021-10-04T22:58:51.4595809Z ##[debug]matchOptions.nocomment: 'false'
2021-10-04T22:58:51.4596384Z ##[debug]matchOptions.nonegate: 'false'
2021-10-04T22:58:51.4596897Z ##[debug]matchOptions.flipNegate: 'false'
**2021-10-04T22:58:51.4597629Z ##[debug]pattern: '**'**
**2021-10-04T22:58:51.4607651Z ##[debug]rooted pattern: 'C:\agent\_work\r3\a\_[DEV] Build Broker library and service\drop\**'**
2021-10-04T22:58:51.4607784Z ##[debug]applying include pattern against original list
**2021-10-04T22:58:51.4663047Z ##[debug]0 matches**
2021-10-04T22:58:51.4664075Z ##[debug]0 final results
2021-10-04T22:58:51.4694579Z found 0 files
2021-10-04T22:58:51.4771997Z ##[section]Finishing: Copy Files to: C:\Temp2
```

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the task in the pipeline or the YAML code of the task? That would help identifying the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved after upgrade to latest version DevOps Server

Also possible workaround from [Microsoft developer community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Azure-DevOps-step-Copy-files-0-matches/1545411?space=22&entry=problem)

> Instead of using Copy files task, you can use a powershell task to run
> the below Copy-Item script to move the files

```powershell
Copy-Item -Path "$(system.defaultworkingdirectory)\folderName\" -Destination "\DestinationFolder" -Exclude ".config" -Recurse
```